# Как внутри хука запустить хук в React Native?

Tags: react-native

Мне нужно при перерисовке компонента- сохранить данные в хранилище.
Я пытаюсь сделать так

```
<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={payload => ScreenUpdated(payload)} />
```

Но внутри ScreenUpdated я не могу сделать,скажем

```
let dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadPosts(0,0))  //loadPosts- подгрузка актуальных данных
 }, [dispatch])
```

как мне взаимодействовать с хранилищем в данном случае?